# Using protected wildcard character in awk field separator doesn't work

Tags: regex, linux, awk, field, special-characters

I have a file that contains paragraphs separated by lines of *(any amount). When I use egrep with the regex of `'^\*+$'` it works as intended, only displaying the lines that contain only stars.

However, when I use the same expression in awk -F or awk FS, it doesn't work and just prints out the whole document, excluding the lines of stars.

Commands that I tried so far:

```
awk -F'^\*+$' '{print $1, $2}' msgs
awk -F'/^\*+$/' '{print $1, $2}' msgs
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="/^\*+$/" } ; { print $1,$2 }' msgs
```

Printing the first field always prints out the whole document, using the first version it excludes the lines with the stars, other versions include everything from the file.

Example input:

```
Par1 test teststsdsfsfdsf
fdsfdsfdsftesyt
fdsfdsfdsf fddsteste345sdfs
***
Par2 dsadawe232343a5edsfe
43s4esfsd s45s45e4t rfgsd45
***
Par3 dsadasd
fasfasf53sdf sfdsf s45 sdfs
dfsf dsf
***
Par4 dasdasda r3ar d afa fs
ds fgdsfgsdfaser ar53d f
***
Par 5 dasdawr3r35a
fsada35awfds46 s46 sdfsds5 34sdf
***
```

Expected output for print $1:

```
Par1 test teststsdsfsfdsf fdsfdsfdsftesyt fdsfdsfdsf fddsteste345sdfs
```

EDIT: Added example input and expected output

Comment: It sounds like you want to use *record* separators instead of *field* separators – but it's hard to tell without seeing representative input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings used as regexps in awk are parsed twice:

1. to turn them into a regexp, and
2. to use them as a regexp.

So if you want to use a string as a regexp (including any time you assign a Field Separator or Record Separator as a regexp) then you need to double any escapes as each iteration of parsing will consume one of them. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps for details.

Good (a literal/constant regexp):

```
$ echo 'a(b)c' | awk '$0 ~ /\(b)/'
a(b)c
```

Bad (a poorly-written dynamic/computed regexp):

```
$ echo 'a(b)c' | awk '$0 ~ "\(b)"'
awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\(' treated as plain `('
a(b)c
```

Good (a well-written dynamic/computed regexp):

```
$ echo 'a(b)c' | awk '$0 ~ "\\(b)"'
a(b)c
```

but IMHO if you're having to double escapes to make a char literal then it's clearer to use a bracket expression instead:

```
$ echo 'a(b)c' | awk '$0 ~ "[(]b)"'
a(b)c
```

Also, `^` in a regexp means "start of **string**" which is only matched at the start of all the input, just like `$` would only be matched at the end of all of the output. `^` does **not** mean "start of **line**" as some documents/scripts may lead you to believe. It only appears to mean that in grep and sed because they are line-oriented and so usually the script is being compared to 1 line at a time, but awk isnt line-oriented, it's record-oriented and so the input being compared to the regexp isn't necessarily just a line (the same is true in sed if you read multiple lines into its hold space).

So to match a line of `*`s as a Record Separator (RS) assuming you're using gawk or some other awk that can treat a multi-char RS as a regexp, you'd have to write this regexp:

```
(^|\n)[*]+(\n|$)
```

but be aware that also matches the newlines before the first and after the last `*`s on the target lines so you need to handle that appropriately in your code.

It seems like this is what you're really trying to do:

```
$ awk -v RS='(^|\n)[*]+(\n|$)' 'NR==1{$1=$1; print}' file
Par1 test teststsdsfsfdsf fdsfdsfdsftesyt fdsfdsfdsf fddsteste345sdfs
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, you really cleared up a lot of mist in my head! That is exactly what I was trying to achieve.